# weblogic.management.ManagementException while deploying

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, weblogic, weblogic12c, application-server

Weblogic 12c deployment from Jenkins randomly getting failed with below exception.

> weblogic.management.ManagementException: There is the same running
>   task 11 for Application#1.5.1     at
>   weblogic.utils.StackTraceDisabled.unknownMethod()

There is no other deployment task is running parallel and weblogic admin console is not holding any locks at that time as well.